# implementation methods to interface xcode script

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I would like to ask if somebody has some user script to copy all implementation methods definitions to the clipboard that can be pasted to the header definitions.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new new userscript with the input set as **Entire Document** and the output set as **Place on Clipboard**. Then past the code below in...

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

text = $stdin.read

for method in text.scan(/\s*([+-]\s*\([^\)]+\)[^\{]+)/)
    puts method[0].strip + ";"
end
```